# Multiplicação Condicional de Coluna - Pandas (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, columns

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1Vxs.png)

Tenho esse df e preciso multiplicar todos os valores da coluna 'QUANTIDADE' por -1 caso o valor da coluna 'TIPOMOV' seja 'S'. Como faço isso?

Comment: Tente passar por todas as linhas e verificar se a coluna anterior contém o S, multiplicando a posterior por -1.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, você poderia utilizar um **apply** para realizar isso, segue abaixo como ficaria o código.

```
df['QUANTIDADE'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['QUANTIDADE'] * -1 if row['TIPOMOV'] == 'S' else row['QUANTIDADE'], axis= 1)
```

Realizei um exemplo de antes e depois de executar isso.

[Imagem antes de executar o Apply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTAEK.png)

[Imagem depois de executar o Apply]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNCJ0.png)

> Caso queria estudar mais sobre o Apply: [Documentação do Apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)
>
> Aqui também tem alguns exemplos de como utilizar o Apply para todas as colunas do Pandas: [Aplicar uma função a múltiplas colunas em Pandas DataFrame](https://www.delftstack.com/pt/howto/python-pandas/pandas-apply-multiple-columns/)

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).